# sql works in MySQLWorkbench but throws MySQLSyntaxErrorException #565 in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

```
      public List<StateGalleryAdListing> getGalleryListing(String state, String category) throws SQLException {

    List<StateGalleryAdListing> adListingList = new ArrayList<>();

    try{

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM stateGalleryListingList WHERE state =" + state +  "AND category = " + category;

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()) {

            StateGalleryAdListing GalleryAdListing = new StateGalleryAdListing();

            GalleryAdListing.setState(rs.getString(1));
            GalleryAdListing.setCategory(rs.getString(2));
            GalleryAdListing.setAdLink(rs.getString(3));
            GalleryAdListing.setImageHeaderTxt(rs.getString(4));
            GalleryAdListing.setImageSrc(rs.getString(5));

            adListingList.add(GalleryAdListing);
        }

    } catch(SQLException ex) {

        ex.getSQLState();
    }

    return adListingList;

}
```

I've also tried to use a PreparedStatment:

```
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM stateGalleryListingList Where state = ? AND category = ?";
 PreparedStatement stmt = conn.conn.prepareStatement(sql);

 stmt.setString(1, state);
 stmt.setString(2, category);

 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

this route still doesn't work, and when I look the error I'm not seeing anything useful. Thanks in advance for any useful advice!

Comment: Check if values for state and category are being inserted properly

Comment: when I debugged the file and saw that those values were inserted correctly. plus I hard coded them in just to make sure that, that wasn't the issue.

Comment: you should write the input used and the errors that you are getting. The full error message that was returned from MySQL

Comment: Also when you are using prepared statement, are you getting an error or no results? please explain what you mean by "still doesn't work"

Comment: error: MySQLSyntaxErrorException #582 
SQLState: SQLState String 42000 
detailMessage String you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?  AND category = ?' at line 1

cause MySQLSyntaxErrorException #582

Comment: Unknown column 'chicago' in 'where clause' is the detail message I get from  
this sql: "SELECT * FROM stateGalleryListingList  WHERE state = chicago AND category = WomenSeekMen"
I don't understand why it thinks the column's value is the columns name.

Answer (score 0):

my issue was here:
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

I didn't need to pass sql into the executeQuery() method. Thanks for your help though guys.